# Formal Languages - Prefix on Language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

> Given a language $L$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$, we say that $u,v \in \Sigma^*$ are *prefix equivalent* over $L$, denoted $u \sim_L v$, if $uw \in L \iff vw \in L$ holds for all $w \in \Sigma^*$.

Is there a language $L$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{ a , b \}$ such that

- $a \sim_L b$, but
- $aa \not\sim_L ba$?

In my opinion, it could be: $L = \{ w \in \Sigma^* | \;\#a\text{ in }w < 2 \;\}$, where "$\#a\text{ in }w$" is the count of signs $a$ in the word $w$.

Thank you

Comment: Could you give your definition of "prefix equivalence"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's a relation on two words. Click here to see formal definition: http://i44.tinypic.com/2n7fgpx.png

Comment: Your proposed example $L$ does not work: $ba \in L$ while $aa \notin L$, so $a$ and $b$ are not prefix-equivalent over this $L$.

Comment: Crosspost with http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18986/formal-languages-prefix-equivalence-language

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a \sim_L b$. Suppose for $w \in \Sigma^\ast$ $a(aw) = (aa)w \in L$, then as $a \sim_L b$, $b(aw) = (ba)w \in L$ as well. And if $a(aw) = (aa)w \notin L$, also $b(aw) = (ba)w \notin L$ for the same reason. So $ba \sim_L aa$.

In essence we can prove: two prefix-equivalent strings remain so if we lengthen them both by the same string.